# Kettle Load csv data into multiple tables

Tags: csv, kettle

I need to load 2 database tables from a single csv file containing mixed data. I also want to maintain parent child relations using foreign key relation.

Below is example of input csv file,

```
<name>,<title>,<department>,<location>
John,Developer,IT, Florida
Mike,Designer,Sales,Nevada
Chris,Designer,Sales,Nevada
```

And below are 2 table structures. Employee table has dept_id as foreign key. Department table will have unique names(no repetitions). According to above sample csv, it should have 2 entries(IT, Sales).

```
DEPARTMENT
-------------
id
name
location


EMPLOYEE
---------
id
name
title
dept_id
```

I am a completely new to using Kettle and any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy. Have you downloaded spoon and started it up yet (The editor for creating transformations)

1. Create a text file input
2. Copy the data from text file input to a group by step to group by department, and then to an insert/update step to get your DEPARTMENT table
3. Copy the data from text file input to another insert/update table step to create your employee table

As for the ID's you can allow the database to generate those as autonumber fields if you like - and do the lookup on whatever the unique requirement is.

I strongly reccomend downloading the tool and having a play - it's so easy once you start.

Comment: I downloaded it, but not really sure what widgets to use and options to choose. Forgot to mention, the 'id's in 2 tables are auto generated sequences by DB.vHow do i pull id from Department table to use in Employee table while inserting. If easy a screenshot or kettle would help.

Comment: I know this comment is quite old now, but there is a "Add sequence" step within pentaho which you could use before inserting into the tables to retrieve the next ID from the DB sequence and then insert into both tables along with your input file data.